# WebSocket vs HTTP - Indicate if the client is online or offline

Tags: node.js, angular, http, websocket, socket.io

I have an `Angular` web application which let users watch other users' profiles.
Those profiles should show if the user is online or offline.
I need some advice on how the "online users list" should be stored.
Should I use `WebSockets` communication to detect user connect and disconnect and base on that add/remove him from the list? Or either send `HTTP` request to the server when application is created on the user's browser (`NgOnInit`) on `AppComponent` and when user leaves (`NgOnDestroy`) on `AppComponent`?

Thanks.

Comment: The only reliable way I know of to see when a user leaves your app/page is by using a webSocket.  You have no guarantee of being able to send an http request when the user wants to leave, particularly if the browser is just shut-down or crashes or perhaps even if the computer goes to sleep.  But, a webSocket will get cleaned up by the OS and your server can see that.  To fully cover yourself, you probably need to send an occasional ping packet from the client to the server and the server can also respond to a lack of receiving a ping packet.

Comment: @jfriend00 Great comment, thank you. One thing I'm not sure I fully understood - should I send the occasional HTTP request from the client as replacement solution to websockets or in addition by websocket emittion?

Comment: webSocket connection and occasionally send a packet to the server over the webSocket (as a ping event) so the server knows the client is still alive.